# Add an additional parameter as a filter to an API call

Tags: support, api

I would like to pass a filter in the API and use this option to receive the favorite count:

However I receive this error:

```
Error in !metadata$has_more : invalid argument type
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add multiple fields in the include field on the create-filter endpoint.

[Filter with `has_more` and `favorite_count`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/create-filter#include=.has_more%3B%20question.favorite_count&base=none&unsafe=false&filter=default&run=true)

So entering `.has_more; question.favorite_count` in the *include* field and using `none` as the *base* filter will give you this filter string: `!O8(x-o_S*`.

If I use that filter string on the `/questions` endpoint I see:

[image: has_more is enabled]

Notice that I copied the filter string into the filter field and that gives me much easier way to inspect and edit my filter. Adding a checkmark here, will update that filter value.

I would advice to also include the `backoff` field as that will tell you if you're within the throttle limits. If backoff is set, wait that many seconds. I doubt your filter is of much use if you don't include `items` as well.

The filter that includes the four fields `.has_more; question.favorite_count; .backoff;  .items` is `!0x(B-)l_JgeP`.

Keep in mind that not all fields need to be in the result. The `backoff` field can either be not present (undefined in JavaScript terms) or come with an positive integer. Your program needs to be able to handle the *field not present* case properly.